# AS3 - How to check if In-App purchase is already purchased?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, storekit, in-app

I'm using Flash CS6 to develop an iOS game with The StoreKit API.
I got 3 In-App purchases in my app and an "All in package" purchase.
They all worked correctly and the restore buttons as well.
I've made an update with a new purchase and consequently a new "All in package" purchase.
The problem is that the new package can not be restored by those who had purchased it to unlock the previous 3 purchase and is treated as a completely new purchased because I changed its ID.
If I leave the ID as it was it will be restored ok but the new purchase would be free.
So I need an event or function that would test if the old package is already purchased or not?